# Why is NGINX passing upstream SSL certificates to client?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

First off, I know that having SSL on an upstream server is not ideal. At this point in time, I just cannot turn it off and need to leave it in place (different story, different team). The issue I'm having is my certificate setup or SSL termination on NGINX. When I hit the site, my browser is throwing errors because the SSL certificate presented is the one on the upstream server it hit (which is expired - again, different story, different team). What am I missing to make the SSL fully terminate at NGINX and that be the certificate in use to the client?

EDIT: fixing my poor grammar.

```
upstream example {
    server 1.2.3.4:443;
    server 4.3.2.1:443;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.org;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key; 

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://example/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
}
```

Comment: In http mode nginx does terminate SSL/TLS with its own cert&key; it MUST because it cannot determine which backend server _if any_ will be used until AFTER it gets the HTTP request which happens AFTER the client-side handshake completes. Make sure your browser isn't using outdated DNS, or a proxy, or somesuch. Try connecting with something like `openssl s_client` (with `-servername` if you have more than one server block!) that does not try to be clever or helpful.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, you got me on the right path to victory. As it turns out, another tech had modified the hosts file, so I wasn't even hitting the NGINX config. Changed the hosts entry and now I'm hitting it. It's still not working but it's not this issue and I know what I need to fix.